# Нарушает ли приложение авторские права?

Tags: android, авторские-права

Мое приложение рандомно предлагает фильм по некоторым параметрам. Результат работы показывается пользователю в виде постера фильма и краткой информации о нем: описание, год, страна. Все данные взяты из отрытых источников. Есть ли вероятность что приложение будет заблокировано за нарушение авторских прав?
Ссылку не прилагаю, дабы не сочли за рекламу.

Comment: «открытые источники» что пишут у себя про использование их информации?

Comment: Что ссылка при использовании ресурсов обязательна, но при гуглении описания появляются сотни сайтов с аналогичным описанием, с которых его можно взять без указания ссылок.

Comment: Вы бы лучше узнали у юриста. Мы тут не специалисты в юридических вопросах, так что можем неправильным советом подвести вам под огромный штраф. Оно вам надо?

Comment: Думаю это самый разумный ответ, так и поступлю.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию. Его стоит задать юристу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это же справочник. Вы же не фильмы показываете.

Comment: Викторины с постерами банят в google play. Так что ... увы...